# Upgrading from create_function to closures

Tags: php

Struggling to understand closures for a couple of days. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Need to re-write this "create_function" as a lambda.

```
$section = preg_replace_callback('/{listing_field_([^{}]*?)_caption}/', create_function('$matches', 'global $config,$or_replace_listing_id,$lang;require_once($config[\'basepath\'].\'/include/listing.inc.php\'); return listing_pages::renderSingleListingItem($or_replace_listing_id, $matches[1],\'caption\');'), $section);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a closure like so:

```
$myClosure = function ($args) {
    // do something;
};
```

`create_function` takes two arguments - the first is an eval'd string of the callable's arguments, the second is the code to execute - so you'd do something like this:

```
$section = preg_replace_callback(
    // Your regex search pattern
    '/{listing_field_([^{}]*?)_caption}/',
    // Your callback
    function ($matches) use ($config, $or_replace_listing_id) {
        require_once $config['basepath'] . '/include/listing.inc.php';
        return listing_pages::renderSingleListingItem(
            $or_replace_listing_id,
            $matches[1],
            'caption'
        );
    },
    // Your subject
    $section
);
```

Note that I've replaced your global variable calls with importing them via `use` into the callback instead, and removed `$lang` because you aren't using it.